# Функция объединения двух массивов

Tags: javascript, jquery

Подскажите есть ли функция в js/jquery для объединения двух массивов в один, следующим образом, чтобы значение первого массива было ключом, а значение второго- значением этого ключа, например

```
var arr1 = ["first","second"];
var arr2 = ["1","2"];
var newArr = ["first":"1","second":"2"];
```

Всем спасибо разобрался!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ассоциативных массивов в js нет. Вместо них используются объекты:

```
var arr1 = ["first","second"];
var arr2 = ["1","2"];

var map = {};

for (var i = 0, l = arr1.length; i < l; i++) {
    var key = arr1[i];
    var val = arr2[i];
    map[key] = val;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
$(function() {
  var arr1 = ["first","second"],
      arr2 = ["1","2"],
      newArr = {};
  for(var i = 0; i < arr1.length; i++){
    newArr[arr1[i]] = arr2[i];
  };
  console.log('first: '+newArr['first']+'; second: '+newArr['second']);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```